# RAM disk + is it possible to mount to RAM instead of disk

Tags: linux, rhel, mount, ram, tmpfs

we have Linux machine that used the disk `/dev/sdb` to save data , we configured the mount point in `/etc/fstab`

disk is `100G` , and mount point is the folder `/data`

now we want to use the memory ( we have `256G` ) , instead of the disk

so is it possible to use the memory RAM `256G` instead to mount the disk?

if yes how to mount the folder `/data` to RAM memory

**What is a RAM disk?**

*Basically, a RAM-based file system is something that creates storage in memory as if it were a partition on a disk – it’s called a RAM disk. Note that RAM is volatile and data is lost at system restart or after a crash. The most important benefit of RAM drives is their speed – even over 10 times faster than SSDs. These very fast storage types are ideal for applications that need speed and fast cache access. Repeat: Data written in this type of file*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More or less like you would for `/dev/sdb1`.

First of all unmount `/dev/sdb1` (you can mount it somewhere else).

```
umount /dev/sdb1
```

You can create another directory and mount the disk there:

```
mkdir /physical-data
mount /dev/sdb1 /physical-data ...(the other options you already have).
```

In `/etc/fstab`, rename "/data" to "/physical-data". Now the hard disk is mounted as before, but `/data` is free to use.

So with the `/data` directory is available as a mount point, you can associate an instance of RAM tmpfs to it, and create a ramdisk there calling it, for example, "ramdisk1" (or whatever else):

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=100G ramdisk1 /data
```

You can set up fstab to automatically remount it upon boot:

```
ramdisk1  /data tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=100G  0  0
```

You could then for example set up a script to run upon boot that would do,

```
rsync -a /physical-data/ /data/
```

assuming your /dev/sdb1 is mounted on `/physical-data`, and a script to be run before shutdown that would copy the content of the modified RAM disk back to `/dev/sdb1`

```
rsync -a --delete /data/ /physical-data/
```

The "--delete" options ensures that if you delete a file from the RAM disk, it will also be deleted later from the hard disk.

This way, your data would reside on the hard disk when power is off, and reappear on the much faster RAM disk upon powering on.

Needless to say, **experiment first and use caution**. You could easily lose all of the data on the hard drive if something goes wrong.